# autocomplete on select country i want to change the list of province and state

Tags: select, autocomplete

Here is what I did. but it is not working:

Non-working code:

```js
$( "#fromPays" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
  source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Pays",
  minLength: 1,
  delay:500,

  if(ui.item.label=='Canada'){ 
    $("#fromEtat").autocomplete({
      source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Province",
      minLength: 1,
       delay:500
    });   
  }
  else if(ui.item.label=='USA'){ 
    $("#fromEtat").autocomplete({
      source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Etat",
      minLength: 1,
      delay:500
    });   
  } 
});
```

If I don't use `.on` and the person changes again, my second list doesn't change:

Working only one time-code:

```
$("#fromPays").autocomplete({
  source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Pays",
  minLength: 1,
  delay:500,
  select: function( event, ui ) {  
    if(ui.item.label=='Canada'){ 
      $("#fromEtat").autocomplete({
        source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Province",
        minLength: 1,
        delay:500
      });   
    } 
    else if(ui.item.label=='USA'){ 
      $("#fromEtat").autocomplete({
        source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Etat",
        minLength: 1,
        delay:500
      });   
    }               
  }  
});
```

If someone has a clue, it will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: here the code if that can interest someone

Answer (score 0):

$("#fromPays").autocomplete({
        source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type=Pays",
        minLength: 1,
        delay:500,
        select: function( event, ui ) {

```
     if(ui.item.label=='Canada'){ fromEtat('Province'); $("#fromEtat").val('').prop({'disabled' : false,'placeholder' : 'Choisir une province'});}
     else  if(ui.item.label=='USA'){ fromEtat('Etat');$("#fromEtat").val('').prop({'disabled' : false,'placeholder' : 'Choisir un état'});}
    else{$("#fromEtat").val('').prop({"disabled": true,'placeholder' : 'Non disponible'});}  

function fromEtat(provinceOuEtat){  
    $("#fromEtat").autocomplete({
    source: "php/listeDeroulante.php?type="+provinceOuEtat,
    minLength: 1,
    delay:500
});
```

}

```
    }  

});
```